# Function to get exclusive lock in SQLite

Tags: database, sqlite, locking, mutex

I was trying to get the exclusive lock for the SQLite database. 
I used **sqlite3_db_mutex(db);** and **sqlite3_mutex_try(mutexObj)** function to acquire lock,
but when I tried to execute query from other shell to the same database, I was able insert row in the table,read the data from table 
I want is to get the LOCK to the database, so that during that time, no-one can make any change to the database, while I've acquired the lock. It is possible in Sqlite  ????

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`sqlite3_db_mutex` locks that connection, and is intended to be used for multiple threads using the same connection.

To lock the database, execute [BEGIN EXCLUSIVE](http://www.sqlite.org/lang_transaction.html).

Comment: Thank you ,It worked ..Now I think..I should've done little more homework before asking it ..

Comment: is there anyway to check if the SQLite is set to journa-l_mode=WAL or journal_mode is DELETE or any other journal_mode ???

Comment: Execute `PRAGMA journal_mode;`.

Comment: Thank you again ..! I really felling bad now, I don't know, how this part really escaped .!

Comment: Is there any way to get a similar locking exclusion but across multiple processes. I thought maybe sql.Open could pass a flag so SQLIte could open the file under a UNIX flock() call.

Comment: @FGM The database lock is a file lock.

Comment: @cl That's what I thought. However, I found out that it does not appear to provide mutual exclusion: I got two goroutines in the same program, using two different connections, successfully interleave requests instead of having the second one be locked out of the DB.

Comment: @FGM That sounds like a bug. Ask a new question.