# How to open a connection with exclusive access to the databalse in Entity Framework Core 5

Tags: c#, sqlite, orm, entity-framework-core, connection

My app runs locally and stores its data in a sqlite database file. I need to ensure that when one instance of the application is running, the other instance **can't** write to the same database file.

If I worked with the database file not through the sqlite engine, I could open it for reading and writing and not close it, but how this can be done in the sqlite engine?

And how this can be done in sqlite provider in Entity Framework?

Comment: Hello. Check if this is what you are looking for: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13404061/how-can-i-lock-a-table-on-read-using-entity-framework

Comment: Check out this SO post: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21886157/function-to-get-exclusive-lock-in-sqlite

Comment: @Kiril1512б, I know that in sqlite, I can lock a table or row. But this is not exactly what I need in this case. I need to lock access to the entire database while my program is still running (until I gave the command to save data and release the database).

Comment: @LocEngineer , I tried using BEGIN EXCLUSIVE. Executed this command at the beginning (even outside of EF - just in a python script for test). However, this did not prevent another process (script) from dropping a table that could potentially be needed by the first one.
And the point here is that as far as I understand, BEGIN EXCLUSIVE can create exclusive access only for the transaction, but not for the whole db session.