# Why don't I see "FOR UPDATE" in the SQL generated by a locked ActiveRecord query?

Tags: sql, ruby-on-rails, rails-activerecord, pessimistic-locking

I'm reading "The Rails 5 Way", and on page 191 I see the following:

> Pessimistic locking takes place at the database level. The SELECT
>   statement generated by Active Record will have a FOR UPDATE (or
>   similar) clause added to it...

The [Rails docs](https://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActiveRecord/Locking/Pessimistic.html) appear to contain the same information:

> Locking::Pessimistic provides support for row-level locking using
>   SELECT … FOR UPDATE and other lock types.
>
> Chain ActiveRecord::Base#find to ActiveRecord::QueryMethods#lock to
>   obtain an exclusive lock on the selected rows:
>
> `Account.lock.find(1)`   # SELECT * FROM accounts WHERE id=1 FOR UPDATE

As an experiment, I wanted to reproduce this `FOR UPDATE` statement on my local machine.  I know that the way to initiate a transaction with pessimistic locking is to call the `.lock` class method (the book gives the example `t = Timesheet.lock.first`).  So I ran the following code in the REPL of a toy Rails app (v 5.1.6) which contains an Order class:

```
irb(main):015:0> Order.transaction do       
irb(main):016:1* o1 = Order.lock.first
irb(main):017:1> o1.update_attributes(name: 'Foo Bar')
irb(main):018:1> end
```

This produced the following output:

```
(0.3ms)  begin transaction
Order Load (0.2ms)  SELECT  "orders".* FROM "orders" ORDER BY "orders"."id" ASC LIMIT ?   [["LIMIT", 1]]
SQL (1.1ms)  UPDATE "orders" SET "name" = ?, "updated_at" = ? WHERE "orders"."id" = ?  [["name", "Foo Bar"], ["updated_at", "2018-11-04 03:01:35.593868"], ["id", 1]]
(0.4ms)  commit transaction
=> true
```

I don't see `FOR UPDATE` in either the `SELECT` or `UPDATE` statements.  Am I doing something wrong when attempting to specify pessimistic locking?  Or do I have an incorrect expectation of what SQL should be output?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I figured out that my toy app was using the default Rails `sqlite` database.  I created a new toy app (`rails new newbie --database=postgresql`), create a new User model with several instances, and ran `User.lock.first`, and I saw the following:

```
irb(main):004:0> User.lock.first
  User Load (1.7ms)  SELECT  "users".* FROM "users" ORDER BY "users"."id" ASC LIMIT $1 FOR UPDATE  [["LIMIT", 1]]
=> #<User id: 1, name: nil, phone: nil, created_at: "2018-11-05 01:28:23", updated_at: "2018-11-05 01:28:23">
```

As you can see, `FOR UPDATE` appears in the SQL query.  From [this Stack Overflow answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5800133/how-to-enforce-sqlite-select-for-update-transaction-behavior-in-sqlalchemy), I see that by default SQLite doesn't support pessimistic locking:

> SELECT ... FOR UPDATE OF ... is not supported. This is understandable
>   considering the mechanics of SQLite in that row locking is redundant
>   as the entire database is locked when updating any bit of it.